Proof that all possible connected subsets of the number axis are exhausted by these nine intervals.
I am studying Introduction to Calculus and Analysis 1 by Richard Courant, SECTION 1.1e, page 12, Question 2 *(a).
The Question is as follows:
An interval may be defined as any connected part of the real continuum. A subset $S$ of the real continuum is said to be connected if with every pair of points $a,b$ in $S$, the set $S$ contains the entire interval $[a,b]$. Aside from the open and closed intervals already mentioned, there are "half-open" intervals $a\leq x<b$ and $a<x\leq b$ (sometimes denoted by $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$, respectively) and the unbounded intervals that may be either the whole real line or a ray, that is, a "half-line" $x\leq a,x<a,x>a,x\geq a$ (sometimes denoted by $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a],(-\infty,a),(a,\infty),[a,\infty)$, respectively).
*(a) Prove that the cases of intervals specified above exhaust all possibilities for connected subsets of the number axis.

My Approach
I don't know if this approach is the standard way or not, it is just was I was able to come up with on my own.
My reasoning is that if a subset of the number axis is connected, then all we are concerned with are its extremities, since its contained part will always be connected - by the definition of connectedness.
A subset of the number axis will always have two extremities - one on each side.
These extremities, if they are finite, will be either open or closed. If they are infinite, then they are open. So, for each extremity, there are three options: (a) finite and closed, (b) finite and open, (c) infinite and open. This leaves us with $3\times3=9$ cases: [Note: the top row corresponds to the right extremity, and the leftmost column corresponds to the left extremity.]
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
&(a)&(b)&(c)\\\hline
(a)&[a,b]&[a,b)&[a,\infty)\\
(b)&(a,b]&(a,b)&(a,\infty)\\
(c)&(-\infty,b]&(-\infty,b)&(-\infty,\infty)
\end{array}
$$
I am not sure if my solution is rigorous or not and would like feedback on this. It feels like my solution just regurgitates the question a bit. I want to know how I should have reasoned through this.

Could we suppose that there are more than 9 possibilities, and then argue that it contradicts the premise that there are only three types of extremity?
